# How to calculate log(sum of terms) from its component log-terms

Tags: math, sum, bayesian, natural-logarithm

(1) The simple version of the problem:

How to calculate log(P1+P2+...+Pn), given log(P1), log(P2), ..., log(Pn), without taking the exp of any terms to get the original Pi. I don't want to get the original Pi because they are super small and may cause numeric computer underflow.

(2) The long version of the problem:

I am using Bayes' Theorem to calculate a conditional probability P(Y|E).

```
P(Y|E) = P(E|Y)*P(Y) / P(E)
```

I have a thousand probabilities multiplying together.

```
P(E|Y) = P(E1|Y) * P(E2|Y) * ... * P(E1000|Y)
```

To avoid computer numeric underflow, I used log(p) and calculate the summation of 1000 log(p) instead of calculating the product of 1000 p.

```
log(P(E|Y)) = log(P(E1|Y)) + log(P(E2|Y)) + ... + log(P(E1000|Y))
```

However, I also need to calculate P(E), which is

```
P(E) = sum of P(E|Y)*P(Y)
```

`log(P(E))` does not equal to the sum of log`(P(E|Y)*P(Y))`. How should I get `log(P(E))` without solving for `P(E|Y)*P(Y)` (they are extremely small numbers) and adding them.

Comment: Do you need the analytic answer? If not you could use log(P(E)) = log[n + sum_{i=1}^n log(P_i)] as an approximation

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
log(P1+P2+...+Pn) = log(P1[1 + P2/P1 + ... + Pn/P1]) 
                  = log(P1) + log(1 + P2/P1 + ... + Pn/P1])
```

which works for any Pi. So factoring out maxP = max_i Pi results in

```
log(P1+P2+...+Pn) = log(maxP) + log(1+P2/maxP + ... + Pn/maxP)
```

where all the ratios are less than 1.